# Does Golang have something like python's ast.literal_eval() for converting a string representation of a map into an actual map object?

Tags: go

I need to convert the string representation of a map object into an actual map object in Go.  Python has this functionality via ast.literal_eval() and looking for something similar in Go.

I've checked out Go's ast lib https://golang.org/pkg/go/ast but I'm not finding similar functionality. Also a third party lib https://github.com/apaxa-go/eval that "appears" to support this via their example code in the readme (though not specific to maps):

```
src:="int8(1*(1+2))"
expr,err:=ParseString(src,"")
if err!=nil{
    return err
}
r,err:=expr.EvalToInterface(nil)
if err!=nil{
    return err
}
fmt.Printf("%v %T", r, r)   // "3 int8"
```

But when attempting with a map:

```
myMap := "map[blah:1 stuff:2 list:3]"
expr, err := eval.ParseString(myMap, "")
if err != nil{
    log.Fatal("%v", err)
}
log.Printf("%v %T", expr, expr)
result, err := expr.EvalToInterface(nil)
if err != nil{
    log.Fatal("%v", err)
}
log.Printf("%v %T", result, result)
```

I get the following error message:

```
2019/10/27 18:38:27.242352 main.go:33: %vexpression:1:9: expected ']', found ':'
```

where line 33 is the expression:

```
expr, err := eval.ParseString(myMap, "")
```

I'm pretty new to Go so I might be approaching this from the wrong direction.  Any help would be appreciated.  The end goal is to take this string representation of a map and convert it to JSON.

Answer (score 0):

The map representation in `myMap` is wrong. You should write it like this

```
map[string]int{"foo": 1, "bar": 2}
```

Comment: indeed, but the goal here is to take a string representation of a map object, like for example on printed out in logs (where it would be a string via copy/paste) and convert it back into a map object and then into a JSON object (or skip the convert into map entirely and just convert to JSON if that makes sense. Example:
``` 
func main(){
  myMap := map[string]int{"foo": 1, "bar": 2}
  fmt.Printf("%v", myMap)
}
```
Would output:
```
map[foo:1 bar:2]
```
Which we would then take that string and convert back into map or JSON object

Comment: Yes, but it's the output format. If you want to evaluate it, you have to format it like this `"map[string]int{\"foo\": 1, \"bar\": 2}"`

Comment: @Ferros `map[blah:1 stuff:2 list:3]` doesn't have enough information about the type. `blah` can be just a string, or a custom type that represents string, or whatever. It also goes same for the value. So it is hard to infer data types just from that string representation. Consider this example: https://play.golang.org/p/E_b0NWX7VkA

Comment: Yep, make sense cause Go is statically typed where python isn't, so they can get away with that.  Made me realize that nested maps/slices would be a nightmare.  Okay I think we can call this not doable.  Thanks everyone for you help!